# PowerShell - filtering for unique values

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have an input CSV file with a column containing information similar to the sample below:

```
805265
995874
805674
984654
332574
339852
```

I'd like to extract unique values into a array based on the leading two characters, so using the above sample my result would be:

80, 99, 98, 33

How might I achieve this using PowerShell?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'd use the [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Group-Object) cmdlet (alias `group`) for this:

```
Import-Csv foo.csv | group {$_.ColumnName.Substring(0, 2)}

Count Name                      Group
----- ----                      -----
    2 80                        {805265, 805674}
    1 99                        {995874}
    1 98                        {984654}
    2 33                        {332574, 339852}
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to powershell and didn't know about this cmdlet.  Thanks for you answer ... i'm able to consolidate quite a few steps using this.  Brilliant!

Comment: `Select-Object -Unique` is elegant, but `Group-Object { $_.PropertyName } | Select-Object -Property Name` is way more performant for me.

Answer (score 26):

Use [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Select-Object) and parameter `-unique`:

```
$values =
'805265',
'995874',
'805674',
'984654',
'332574',
'339852'

$values |
  Foreach-Object { $_.Substring(0,2) } |
  Select-Object -unique
```

If conversion to int is needed, then just cast it to `[int]`:

```
$ints =
  $values |
  Foreach-Object { [int]$_.Substring(0,2) } |
  Select-Object -unique
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use a hash table:

```
$values = @(805265, 995874, 805674, 984654, 332574, 339852)

$ht = @{}

$values | foreach {$ht[$_ -replace '^(..).+','$1']++}

$ht.keys

99
98
33
80
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a new array with items containing the first two characters and then use [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Select-Object) to give you the unique items like this:

```
$newArray = @()
$csv = Import-Csv -Path C:\your.csv
$csv | % {
    $newArray += $_.YourColumn.Substring(0, 2)
}
$newArray | Select-Object -Unique
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another option instead of using `Select-Object -unique` would be to use the [Get-Unique](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/PowerShell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/Get-Unique) cmdlet (or its alias `gu`; see the [detailed description here](https://ss64.com/ps/get-unique.html)) as demonstrated below:

```
$values = @(805265, 995874, 805674, 984654, 332574, 339852)
$values | % { $_.ToString().Substring(0,2) } | Get-Unique
# Or the same using the alias
$values | % { $_.ToString().Substring(0,2) } | gu
```